# Unity custom class shared by all scripts and objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please, in working on project in unity 2017, where i am often using `Vector2((int),(int))` together with 2d arrays.
problem is that `Vector2` converts values to `float`, while array values need to be referenced with `integer`.

First i would like to know if or how its possible to make custom class like IntVector2() which would be used same way `Vector2()` is, which would store values as integers, to be shared across all objects and scripts, as i need to use this in almost all scripts. i managed to create class which behaves as i need, but im unable to find how to make it available globally without having to copy-paste class constructor everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about performance, then stick with structs. There's no need to roll your own either. See: [Vector2Int](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html)

> **Vector2Int**
>
> Representation of 2D vectors and points using integers.
>
> This structure is used in some places to represent 2D positions and vectors that don't require the precision of floating-point.